# Limitar consulta no index mas não na combo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Boa tarde,

No ERP da empresa temos uma consulta no Index que está limitada a 80 registros.
O problema é que no create temos combos que trazem mais de 150 registros e também esta limitando a 80 registros.

Como eu posso fazer para deixar apenas no index sem ter de criar outro método?

```
private StringBuilder LimitarRetornoLinhas()
    {
        var sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.Append("SELECT * FROM (" + Environment.NewLine);
        sql.Append(_sql.ToString());
        sql.Append(" ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 80 ");
        return sql;
    }
```

-

```
public List<Fabricante> Selecionar()

    {
        var fabricantes = new List<Fabricante>();

        _sql.Append(" ORDER BY FAB_NOME ");

        StringBuilder sql = LimitarRetornoLinhas();
        Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conexao.AbrirConexao();

        dt = conexao.ObterDataTable(sql.ToString());

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                fabricantes.Add(Mapear(dt.Rows[i]));
            }
        }

        return fabricantes;
    }
```

Comment: porque não parametriza o método com o limite desejado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altere para receber como parâmetro a quantidade de registros desejado:

```
private StringBuilder LimitarRetornoLinhas(int quantidadeRegistros = 80)
{
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();

    sql.Append("SELECT * FROM (" + Environment.NewLine);
    sql.Append(_sql.ToString());
    sql.Append(string.Format(" ) WHERE ROWNUM <= {0} ", quantidadeRegistros));

    return sql;
}
```

Agora basta chamar seu método passando a quantidade de registros desejado:

```
StringBuilder query = LimitarRetornoLinhas(150);
```

Comment: eu só deixaria um valor padrão... para não impactar outros lugares em que o método possa estar sendo invocado e se deseja o default já definido na regra de negócio

Comment: Muito bem observado, irei alterar a resposta. Obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado. Abriu minha mente.

Comment: Eu fiz de um modo diferente pois eu iria fixar um valor. Não seria interessante para mim.

Answer (score 0):

```
private StringBuilder LimitarRetornoLinhas(bool carregarTodos)
    {
        var sql = new StringBuilder();
        if (carregarTodos == false)
        {
            sql.Append("SELECT * FROM (" + Environment.NewLine);
            sql.Append(_sql.ToString());
            sql.Append($" ) WHERE ROWNUM <= 80"); 
        }
        else
        {
            sql.Append(_sql.ToString());
        }

        return sql;
    }
```

-

```
public List<Fabricante> Selecionar(bool carregarTodos)
    {
        var fabricantes = new List<Fabricante>();

        _sql.Append(" ORDER BY FAB_NOME ");

        StringBuilder sql = LimitarRetornoLinhas(carregarTodos);
        Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        conexao.AbrirConexao();

        dt = conexao.ObterDataTable(sql.ToString());

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                fabricantes.Add(Mapear(dt.Rows[i]));
            }
        }

        return fabricantes;
    }
```

Comment: Mas se o carregarTodos for true não trás ninguém?

Comment: Eu passo como true no controller do cadastro que puxa a informação deste repositório e ele traz todos os fabricantes e no index limita em 80 registros.